# ExtJS - Create custom structure for ComboBox

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm attemtping to create a custom ComboBox control. The control will have a button on either side of the ComboBox itself, something like this:

```
[<-]   [ --------------- V ]    [->]
```

These buttons will be "next" and "previous" which will allow the user to quickly toggle between options in the dropdown (moving down and up respectively).

I've tried overriding the `defaultAutoCreate` config of the ComboBox, but I'm getting some odd behavior. Here's what I've tried so far: (this is all inside of a custom class extending ComboBox)

```
initComponent: function () {

    // default ComboBox structure
    var comboStructure = { 
        tag: 'span',
        children: [
            { tag: 'a', cls: 'nav prev', html: 'Previous' },
            { tag: 'input', type: 'text', size: '24', autocomplete: 'off' },
            { tag: 'a', cls: 'nav next', html: 'Next' }
        ]
    };

    console.log(comboStructure);

    var config = {
        triggerAction: 'all',
        lazyRender: true,
        mode: 'local',
        store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [
                'myId',
                'displayText'
            ],
            data: [[1, 'Banner #1'], [2, 'Banner #2']]
        }),
        valueField: 'myId',
        displayField: 'displayText',
        defaultAutoCreate: comboStructure
    };

    Ext.apply(this, config);

    IbwUi.controls.PreviewBannerSelectDropdown.superclass.initComponent(this);

}
```

The 2nd "child" of the comboStructure is actually the default value that gets initialized for ComboBox, I looked at the source code. The code works without error, but there's some odd behavior with the rendering of the combo itself, see here:

[image: Weird DOM display]

Any ideas on how to add my custom elements around the ComboBox when it renders?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it like this. Instead put all three components into a container class that implements the logic you need.

Comment: I could do that, and it's probably easier, but I'm still wondering why this solution doesn't work. I noticed that the "arrow" for the ComboBox doesn't appear to be a part of the default structure...that's why its getting added afterwards.